# input radio list with image changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently trying to make a radio list where the 3 choices are the following:

Salad
Spaghetti
Ice cream

I wrote it like this:

```
<div id="radiobuttons">
  <label><input name="vf" type="radio" value="0"checked/>Salade</label> 
  <br>
  <label><input name="vf" type="radio" value="1"/>Spaghetti</label>
  <br>
  <label><input name="vf" type="radio" value="2"/>Creme glacee</label>
  <br>
</div>
```

Now right next to the list I want a picture of a salad at start because salad is checked, but when the user chooses spaghetti, that image changes to a picture of spaghetti. Same for ice cream.

I tried a lot of functions but it just doesnt work.

Can someone help ?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("input:radio[name=vf]").change(function() { //name = button group 
    name
    if (this.value == "0") {
      $("#vf").attr( //image file name
        'src', '/images/salade.jpg' //image path
      );
    }
    else if (this.value == "1") {
      $("#vf").attr( //image file name
        'src', '/images/spaghetti.jpg' //image path
      );
    }
    else {
      $("#vf").attr( //image file name
        'src', '/images/cremeglacee.jpg'    //image path             
      );
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: share your JQuery script, what you are trying

Comment: Show the JS or jQuery code you tryed which is closest as you want. And tell what is wrong about it. By just providing 3 inputs and nothing else makes your question **unclear**.

Comment: Ive edited my post, sorry im kind of struggling with posting codes here hope you guys can understand what im trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```js
function changeImage(imgUrl){
  document.querySelector("#food").src=imgUrl;
}
```

```css
img{
  max-width:200px;
  max-height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#radiobuttons{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="radiobuttons">
    <label><input name="vf" type="radio" onclick="changeImage('http://i.imgur.com/vEp0R6u.jpg')" value="0"/>Salade</label>
    <br>
    <label><input name="vf" type="radio" onclick="changeImage('http://i.imgur.com/POwjufy.jpg')" value="1"/>Spaghetti</label>
    <br>
    <label><input name="vf" type="radio" onclick="changeImage('http://i.imgur.com/38igW6A.jpg')" value="2"/>Creme glacee</label>
    <br>
  </div>
  <img id="food">
</body>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed my friend, thank you so much.

Comment: This forum is amazing btw, this was my first question.

Comment: I'm happy that this solution fit for you,can you please mark the answer as selected by clicking the tick?

Comment: Just another question, I notice you used imgur, what if I want to use pictures on my computer and not hosted on imgur?

Comment: And I did upvote the answer but it says Its not recorded because its new

Comment: Just add the path to the picture (if the picture is in the same folder of the page is sufficent to specify name of the picture with the extension ) example:changeImage('photo.jpg')